# Is there a way to programatically check airplane mode status?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am creating project in which i required API to know airplane mode status on in windows phone.or any other way to know status.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any direct API that accesses the status of Airplane Mode directly but essentially it shuts down network availability so you could test for that using the [DeviceNetworkInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation.devicenetworkinformation.aspx) class. (It's a good idea to test this on a device but I believe this would simulate Airplane Mode)

```
public bool IsAirplaneMode()
{
    bool[] networks = new bool[4] { DeviceNetworkInformation.IsNetworkAvailable, DeviceNetworkInformation.IsCellularDataEnabled, DeviceNetworkInformation.IsCellularDataRoamingEnabled, DeviceNetworkInformation.IsWiFiEnabled };
    return (networks.Count(n => n) < 1);
}
```

If you'd like to ask the user to turn it on or off, you can launch the setting via [ConnectionStatusTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.connectionsettingstask.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DeviceNetworkInformation` class to determine the state of the network access.
If you need an event for this, you can use `DeviceNetworkInformation.NetworkAvailabilityChanged`.

Exmple:

```
DeviceNetworkInformation.NetworkAvailabilityChanged += new EventHandler<NetworkNotificationEventArgs>(ChangeDetected);
```