# How to detect airplane mode programmatically in laptop with windows 10 using uwp

Tags: uwp, windows-10

I want to detect airplane mode in laptop (windows 10) ( Universal Windows Application ) programmatically. Is there any way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to programatically check airplane mode status?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17483136/is-there-a-way-to-programatically-check-airplane-mode-status)

Comment: I had tried using the solution from How to detect airplane mode programmatically in windows phone 10, but it is throwing exception in the code since it is respective only to phone. I could not find API to detect airplane mode in laptop. Is there any API ?

Comment: Semi accurate it would be the registry keys in ```HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\RadioManagement\SystemRadioState``` (and maybe CurrentControlSet instead of ControlSet001). Reading this value should work. Writing is a different thing, because afaik Windows handles the "Flight Mode" as a Hardware driver thing which is more complicated. Also I don't know how far you can go with a UWP app...

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `NetworkInformation` class from the namespace `Windows.Networking.Connectivity`.

A method like this one should help you:

```
private bool IsConnected() {
    var connectionProfile = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
    return (connectionProfile != null &&
          (connectionProfile.GetNetworkConnectivityLevel() == NetworkConnectivityLevel.InternetAccess || 
          connectionProfile.GetNetworkConnectivityLevel() == NetworkConnectivityLevel.ConstrainedInternetAccess));
}
```

Comment: This UWP method verifies whether the internet connection is available or not. I need to get the airplane mode status

Comment: This API does not exist.